# Save and restore data in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `ListFragment` where I want to save its data using `onSaveInstanceState`and restore it in `onCreateView`, but something strange happens.

**I use this code for saving data:**

```
private ArrayList<TuplaFacturaWS> facturas;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("save");

    //TuplaUsuario.usuario
    savedInstanceState.putString("usuario", myApplication.getUsuarioActual().getUsuario());
    //TuplaUsuario.password
    savedInstanceState.putString("password", myApplication.getUsuarioActual().getPassword());
    //TuplaUsuario.cups
    ArrayList<TuplaCupsWS> arrayCups = myApplication.getUsuarioActual().getCups();
    savedInstanceState.putInt("numCups", arrayCups.size());
    for(int cups = 0; cups < arrayCups.size(); cups++) {
        //TuplaUsuario.cups.CUPS, TuplaUsuario.cups.Tarifa, TuplaUsuario.cups.Direccion
        savedInstanceState.putString("cups"+cups, arrayCups.get(cups).getCups());
        savedInstanceState.putString("tarifa"+cups, arrayCups.get(cups).getTarifa());
        savedInstanceState.putString("direccion"+cups, arrayCups.get(cups).getDireccion());
        //TuplaUsuario.cups.facturas
        System.out.println("N facturas on save: "+arrayCups.get(cups).getFacturas().size());
        ArrayList<TuplaFacturaWS> arrayFacturas = arrayCups.get(cups).getFacturas();
        savedInstanceState.putInt("numFacturas"+cups, arrayFacturas.size());
        for(int factura = 0; factura < arrayFacturas.size(); factura++) {
            savedInstanceState.putString("factura"+factura,
                    arrayFacturas.get(factura).getFactura());
            savedInstanceState.putDouble("importe"+factura, 
                    arrayFacturas.get(factura).getImporte());
            savedInstanceState.putLong("fecha"+factura, 
                    arrayFacturas.get(factura).getFecha().getTime());
            savedInstanceState.putString("plan"+factura,    
                    arrayFacturas.get(factura).getPlan());
            savedInstanceState.putString("estado"+factura,  
                    arrayFacturas.get(factura).getEstado());
            savedInstanceState.putString("pdf"+factura, 
                    arrayFacturas.get(factura).getPdf());
            savedInstanceState.putString("anexo"+factura,   
                    arrayFacturas.get(factura).getAnexo());
        }
    }
    //TuplaUsuario.cupsActual
    savedInstanceState.putInt("cupsActual", myApplication.getUsuarioActual().getCupsActual());
}
```

### **Situation 1**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_facturas, container, false);
    // Get the application instance
    myApplication = (MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication();
    facturas = myApplication.getFacturas();

    System.out.println("num facturas on create view: "+facturas.size());

    //...
}
```

What happens is:

- When load view for first time, view shows 5 "facturas". `onCreateView`prints "num facturas on create view: 5".
- When change orientation, view shows same 5 "facturas". `onSaveInstanceState`prints "N facturas on save: 5", and `onCreateView`prints "num facturas on create view: 5". -> It is correct.
- When change orientation again, view shows no "factura". `onSaveInstanceState`prints "N facturas on save: 0", and `onCreateView`prints "num facturas on create view: 0". -> It is wrong.

### **Situation 2**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_facturas, container, false);
    // Get the application instance
    myApplication = (MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            System.out.println("bundle not null");
            myApplication.nuevoUsuarioActual();
            //TuplaUsuario.usuario
            myApplication.getUsuarioActual().setUsuario(savedInstanceState.getString("usuario"));
            //TuplaUsuario.password
            myApplication.getUsuarioActual().setPassword(savedInstanceState.getString("password"));
            //TuplaUsuario.cups
            ArrayList<TuplaCupsWS> arrayCups = new ArrayList<TuplaCupsWS>();
            int numCups = savedInstanceState.getInt("numCups");
            for(int cups = 0; cups < numCups; cups++) {
                TuplaCupsWS tuplaCups = new TuplaCupsWS();
                //TuplaUsuario.cups.CUPS, TuplaUsuario.cups.Tarifa, TuplaUsuario.cups.Direccion
                tuplaCups.setCups(savedInstanceState.getString("cups"+cups));
                tuplaCups.setTarifa(savedInstanceState.getString("tarifa"+cups));
                tuplaCups.setDireccion(savedInstanceState.getString("direccion"+cups));
                //TuplaUsuario.cups.facturas
                ArrayList<TuplaFacturaWS> arrayFacturas = new ArrayList<TuplaFacturaWS>();
            int numFacturas = savedInstanceState.getInt("numFacturas"+cups);
            System.out.println("n facturas: "+numFacturas);
            for(int factura = 0; factura < numFacturas; factura++) {

                TuplaFacturaWS tuplaFactura = new TuplaFacturaWS();
                tuplaFactura.setFactura(savedInstanceState.getString("factura"+factura));
                tuplaFactura.setImporte(savedInstanceState.getDouble("importe"+factura));
                tuplaFactura.setFecha(new Date(savedInstanceState.getLong("fecha"+factura)));
                tuplaFactura.setPlan(savedInstanceState.getString("plan"+factura));
                tuplaFactura.setEstado(savedInstanceState.getString("estado"+factura));
                tuplaFactura.setPdf(savedInstanceState.getString("pdf"+factura));
                tuplaFactura.setAnexo(savedInstanceState.getString("anexo"+factura));
                arrayFacturas.add(tuplaFactura);

            }
                tuplaCups.setFacturas(arrayFacturas);
                arrayCups.add(tuplaCups);
            }
            myApplication.getUsuarioActual().setCups(arrayCups);
            //TuplaUsuario.cupsActual
            myApplication.getUsuarioActual().setCupsActual(
                    savedInstanceState.getInt("cupsActual"));

    }

    facturas = myApplication.getFacturas();

    System.out.println("num facturas on create view: "+facturas.size());

    //...
}
```

In that case what happens is:

- When load view for first time, view shows 5 "facturas". `onCreateView`prints "num facturas on create view: 5".
- When change orientation, view shows same 5 "facturas". `onSaveInstanceState`prints "N facturas on save: 5", `Bundle`is not null, and `onCreateView`prints "n facturas: 0" and "num facturas on create view: 0". -> It is wrong.
- When change orientation again, the same happens.

If I add

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

is the same as in Situation 1.

I can't find where the problem is.

Comment: is `numCups` getting the correct value after the orientation change?

Comment: Yes, it has to be 1 and it is.

Comment: post the code that you are using to save the other data then. it sounds like you are saving at least the numCups value correctly.

Comment: I've edited my question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you calling this `int numFacturas = savedInstanceState.getInt("numFacturas");` in the onCreateView(), but I don't see where you are setting that value in the onSaveInstanceState().

This would result in numFacturas = 0, therefore never getting in to your loop to populate the array.